# Applying Super-Resolution to differently sized images

Tags: image-processing, image, neural-networks

I would like to make some images larger and noticed that there is a page in the documentation for doing super-resolution using a network structure. It's called "A Model for Super-Resolution." You can find it here:

https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/machine-learning-for-images/a-model-for-super-resolution.html?product=mathematica

It starts out loading a NetModel

```
net = NetModel["Very Deep Net for Super-Resolution"]
```

and then provides a way to call the model. It starts like:

```
netevaluate[img_, imgScale_] := 
       Block[{interpolated, ycbcr, channels, resizedNet, diff},
```

and goes on for a while. I can successfully call this if I make my image be of size 255 by 255 pixels, which is the image size that it seems to expect. But if my image is larger, it beeps and quits the kernel.

My question is: is there a way to use this (or a similar function) with arbitrarily sized images?

Comment: I tested the sample image on Windows 10 x64 with Mathematica 13.0.1 and 16 GB ram, 3 times (200 -> 400, 400 -> 800, 800 -> 1600 pixel) no beeps, works fine but I did see a huge spike in memory usage although its `MaxMemoryUsed` on the last step was `263,874,784` bytes, the task manager showed a much higher gap.

Comment: Out of memory errors are acceptable but crashing the kernel or front-end is never acceptable behaviour for a software. Consequently, this is a *bug* that should be [reported to Wolfram Technical support](https://support.wolfram.com/12507).

Comment: Does adding at the beginning of notebook open `$HistoryLength=0` help?

Comment: It is definitely a memory problem. $HistoryLength=0 does not help. I tried for 300x360, 500x560, 800x860 and they all worked. I got an out-or-memory error for 1000x1060. My original size (1080x1920) still beeps and quits. Guess I need to use smaller images! Thanks to josh and Ben Izd for the hints.

Comment: You could use `ImagePartition`, then increase the resolution on the parts and then `ImageAssemble` to rejoin the parts.

Comment: @rhermans mma unfortunately crashes the front end *a lot* for various things, i’ve given up on wolfram solving them, regardless of how many bug submitted.